# Vibration When Accelerating Only When Car Is Full

Tags: noise, vibration

I have a manual 2015 BMW 320i with 33,000 miles. Lately, I’ve noticed a vibrational noise when accelerating—mostly when in first or second gear—but ONLY when there are four people in the car! I can’t replicate the noise when it’s just me or me and my spouse. It SEEMS to be coming from near or under the center console. The noise does NOT occur if I’m stopped and gun the engine. That points to transmission or suspension, maybe, but why no noise when the car is not full? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a motor or transmission mount. They use rubber bushings. When the engine is being torqued under a load, the engine will twist and if the rubber bushing is worn the engine vibrations will transfer to the chassis.